# Save date time in database and match with Current system time

Tags: java, date, spring-mvc, scheduler

I Have an image model

```
@Entity
public class Image {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "CAPTION")
private String caption;

@Column(name = "IMAGE_PATH")
private String imagePath;

@Column(name = "IMAGE_NAME")
private String imageName;

@Column(name = "NUMBER_OF_VIEW")
private Integer numberOfView;

@Column(name = "PUBLISH_TIME")
private Date publishDate;
```

when user upload a image he select a date-time and image model is saved with publishDate date in this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH::mm" format in database.Now i have a scheduler

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * ?")
public void sendNotification() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    Date currentDate = new Date();

    List<ImageInfo> listImageInfo = imageInfoDao.getImageOfParticularDate(currentDate);
    if (listImageInfo.size() > 0) {

        List<User> listUser = userDao.getAppUser(ACTIVE);
        for (ImageInfo imageInfo : listImageInfo) {
            for (User user : listUser) {
                pushNotification(user.getRegId(), pushGroupNumNotification(imageInfo.getGroupNum()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which check repeatedly every 5 second  whether  a system time is equal to uploded image publish time.how can i check this equality.i am using Date . Should i use Datetime??

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Date.equals()` will [compare dates based on milliseconds](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/date_equals.htm) elapsed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Given that you are initializing them on minute-granularity and comparing them based on minutes, this method will suffice, as all other more granular time units will be set to default (seconds, milliseconds etc.) and therefore match.

Just make sure that you are using the right Formatter. In your question you first refer to the format written to database as "yyyy-MM-dd HH::mm" but in your code you are using "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm".